# Extracting weekdays from an xts object and keeping the extracted weekdays as an xts object

Tags: r

I want to try and extract the weekdays from the `index` of an `xts` object similar to below:

```
           XLE.Open XLE.High XLE.Low XLE.Close XLE.Volume XLE.Adjusted
2018-09-04    74.78    74.84   73.98     74.28   15094700     68.47708
2018-09-05    73.94    74.22   73.19     74.18    9598100     68.38488
2018-09-06    73.90    74.15   72.61     72.81   14406400     67.12192
```

I can use the `.indexwday` from the `xts` package:

```
> .indexwday(d)
 [1] 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1
[46] 2 3 4 5 1
```

However I lose the `xts` object.

I can also use `weekdays(time(d))`:

```
> weekdays(time(d))
 [1] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"
 [8] "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
[15] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"  
[22] "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday" 
[29] "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"   
[36] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"
[43] "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
[50] "Monday"
```

But again I lose the `xts` structure.

If I apply something trivial such as:

```
ifelse(d[, "XLE.Open"] > d[, "XLE.Close"], 1, 0)
```

The output is:

```
> ifelse(d[, "XLE.Open"] > d[, "XLE.Close"], 1, 0)
           XLE.Open
2018-09-04        1
2018-09-05        0
2018-09-06        1
2018-09-07        0
2018-09-10        1
2018-09-11        0
2018-09-12        1
2018-09-13        0
2018-09-14        0
2018-09-17        1
```

It keeps the `xts` structure. So my question is how can I get the days of the week whilst also not removing the `xts` structure?

Expected output:

```
           weekdays
2018-09-04        2
2018-09-05        3
2018-09-06        4
2018-09-07        5
2018-09-10        1
2018-09-11        2
2018-09-12        3
2018-09-13        4
2018-09-14        5
2018-09-17        1
```

Data:

```
d <- structure(c(74.779999, 73.940002, 73.900002, 72.540001, 73.169998, 
72.699997, 74.059998, 73.720001, 73.879997, 74.449997, 74.910004, 
74.889999, 75.419998, 75.010002, 75.760002, 76.68, 76.220001, 
76.25, 75.589996, 76.019997, 76.980003, 77.199997, 77.239998, 
77.089996, 76.589996, 77.370003, 77.919998, 74.620003, 73.519997, 
72.989998, 72.589996, 72.849998, 71.860001, 71.809998, 71.480003, 
69.699997, 69.220001, 66.980003, 66.43, 66.970001, 65.199997, 
67.400002, 67.300003, 68.480003, 68.379997, 68.860001, 69.900002, 
69.82, 67.709999, 68.970001, 74.839996, 74.220001, 74.150002, 
72.93, 73.470001, 73.879997, 74.57, 74.010002, 74.540001, 74.879997, 
75.379997, 75.410004, 75.709999, 75.349998, 76.529999, 77.010002, 
76.620003, 76.349998, 76.540001, 77.110001, 77.129997, 77.720001, 
77.709999, 77.410004, 77.220001, 78.360001, 78.050003, 74.669998, 
73.739998, 73.290001, 73.120003, 73.07, 72.839996, 72.580002, 
71.629997, 69.720001, 69.239998, 67.669998, 67.300003, 67.059998, 
66.910004, 68.290001, 68.050003, 68.980003, 68.959999, 69.160004, 
70.360001, 70.370003, 68.940002, 69.260002, 73.980003, 73.190002, 
72.610001, 71.779999, 72.75, 72.5, 73.82, 73.230003, 73.849998, 
74.199997, 74.860001, 74.82, 75.029999, 74.5, 75.699997, 76.580002, 
75.82, 75.75, 75.550003, 76.019997, 76.339996, 76.980003, 76.720001, 
76.690002, 76.290001, 77.040001, 75, 72.25, 71.889999, 72.370003, 
72.290001, 71.910004, 71.709999, 71.480003, 70.309998, 67.910004, 
66.150002, 66.529999, 65.379997, 64.370003, 64.900002, 67.07, 
66.610001, 66.879997, 68.220001, 68.190002, 69.099998, 68.370003, 
67.339996, 66.940002, 74.279999, 74.18, 72.809998, 72.800003, 
72.769997, 73.459999, 73.839996, 73.870003, 74.260002, 74.379997, 
74.870003, 75.099998, 75.120003, 75.099998, 76.199997, 76.690002, 
75.949997, 75.949997, 75.739998, 76.790001, 76.870003, 77.489998, 
77.169998, 77.160004, 77.099998, 77.790001, 75.349998, 72.800003, 
73, 72.389999, 72.989998, 72.529999, 72.169998, 71.529999, 70.739998, 
68.889999, 66.169998, 66.980003, 66.480003, 65.239998, 66.75, 
67.160004, 67.730003, 67.559998, 68.690002, 69.010002, 70.139999, 
68.620003, 68.5, 67.080002, 15094700, 9598100, 14406400, 10134400, 
8911700, 14281600, 12689400, 11037400, 9494300, 14728900, 10223500, 
10911500, 12512400, 13710100, 12784500, 13027600, 12728600, 10672100, 
14833100, 12712600, 9468400, 13244800, 15192700, 11983200, 11578600, 
16816700, 26405300, 35592100, 23579000, 11590400, 14571100, 15804200, 
16586700, 13568100, 12294500, 26477700, 28100200, 25333300, 25579900, 
24459800, 26397400, 17287800, 21475800, 21212500, 13231600, 13072100, 
16662900, 15144900, 22917800, 18041600, 68.477081, 68.38488, 
67.121918, 67.112701, 67.085037, 67.72113, 68.071442, 68.099113, 
68.458649, 68.569275, 69.020988, 69.233017, 69.25145, 69.709068, 
70.73011, 71.184929, 70.498047, 70.498047, 70.303116, 71.277748, 
71.352013, 71.927505, 71.63047, 71.621201, 71.565498, 72.205963, 
69.941116, 67.574173, 67.759811, 67.193596, 67.750519, 67.32354, 
66.989403, 66.395325, 65.662048, 63.944851, 61.42009, 62.171951, 
61.70784, 60.55685, 61.958458, 62.339031, 62.868111, 62.710316, 
63.759197, 64.056236, 65.105103, 63.694229, 63.582836, 62.264774
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1583013196.93326, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), index = structure(c(1536019200, 1536105600, 1536192000, 
1536278400, 1536537600, 1536624000, 1536710400, 1536796800, 1536883200, 
1537142400, 1537228800, 1537315200, 1537401600, 1537488000, 1537747200, 
1537833600, 1537920000, 1538006400, 1538092800, 1538352000, 1538438400, 
1538524800, 1538611200, 1538697600, 1538956800, 1539043200, 1539129600, 
1539216000, 1539302400, 1539561600, 1539648000, 1539734400, 1539820800, 
1539907200, 1540166400, 1540252800, 1540339200, 1540425600, 1540512000, 
1540771200, 1540857600, 1540944000, 1541030400, 1541116800, 1541376000, 
1541462400, 1541548800, 1541635200, 1541721600, 1541980800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(50L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("XLE.Open", "XLE.High", "XLE.Low", 
"XLE.Close", "XLE.Volume", "XLE.Adjusted")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an assignment

```
d[, "XLE.Open"] <- +(d[, "XLE.Open"] > d[, "XLE.Close"])
```

---

For the index, we can just wrap with `xts` and specify the `order.by` with `index` of 'd'

```
d1 <- xts(.indexwday(d), order.by = index(d))
colnames(d1) <- "weekdays"
str(d1)
#An ‘xts’ object on 2018-09-04/2018-11-12 containing:
#  Data: int [1:50, 1] 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr "weekdays"
#  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
```

---

If we also load `tsibble`

```
library(tsibble)
```

some functions are getting masked

> The following object is masked from ‘package:zoo’:
>
> index

resulting in

```
d1 <- xts(.indexwday(d), order.by = index(d))
```

> Error: x is not a tsibble.
>       Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

We can directly specify the package name with `::`

```
d1 <- xts(.indexwday(d), order.by = zoo::index(d))
```

Comment: I get for the `xts` part: `> xts(.indexwday(d), order.by = index(d))
Error: x is not a tsibble.`

Comment: @user113156 i didn't find any tsibble attribute in your structure

Comment: Me neither, I will re-start R and run the code again

Comment: @user113156 okay, got it, the `xts` is getting masked when you load the `tsibble`.  You can do `xts::xts(.indexway(d), order.by = index(d))`

Comment: @user113156 actually, `index` was from `zoo`.  So, please use the updated code in my post

Comment: Just finished restarting the AWS instance so I will try it.

Comment: You can also use `time(d)` instead of `index(d)` or use in recent versions of R `library(tsibble, exclude = "index")`